# Save the model with the best optuna trial

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, hyperparameters, optuna

I have trained a model using optuna (PyTorch) where number of trials was 5.

This is what my output looks like :
[image: Output from optuna trials on lr and optmizer]

Now, the 4th trial is the best trial. I dont just want the best parameter values, I want to save the model with these values for lr and optimizer. I want to know how that can be done.